# IllegalArgumentException while calling REST service

Tags: apache-camel

I am getting following error, while trying to invoke REST service through cxfrs endpoint.

```
org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline | 130 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.10.0.redhat-60024 | Message exchange has failed: so breaking out of pipeline for exchange: Exchange[Message: [Body is null]] Exception: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientWebApplicationException: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientWebApplicationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: IllegalArgumentException invoking 
http://someurl:8181/cxf/testService/test.xml?q1=new&q2=qwe: Illegal character(s) in message header value:
```

I am using spring DSL to write camel code.
Following is code snippet for CXF-RS configuration:

```
<cxf:rsClient id="rsClient" address=" http://someurl:8181/cxf/testService"
loggingFeatureEnabled="true"/>
```

And we calling rsClient it through Camel code using following code:

```
<to id="outEndpoint" uri="cxfrs://bean://rsClient"/>
```

Can anyone please suggest what could be the reason?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "removeHeaders"?
Kindly find the details in the link provided:
http://camel.apache.org/how-to-avoid-sending-some-or-all-message-headers.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the reason of the `IllegalArgumentException`, but the `address` attribute for `rsClient` has a leading whitespace: `" http://someurl:8181/cxf/testService"`

(If removing the white space does not solve your problem, it would be helpful if you could show us the whole route definition.)